# НЕ получается получить доступ к DIV во время парсинга, возвращается пустой массив

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Нужно получить div.main-wrapper для последующего "углубления", чтобы достать div.block-i-need. Ниже упрощенный код с практически такой же структурой, чтобы не вставлять кучу кода с [реального сайта, с которым  работаю](https://vkmix.com/tasks/vk/all). **Но в место блока, получаю пустой массив**. Спасите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="ul">
            <div class="block-i-need">hello</div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("https://vkmix.com/tasks/vk/all");
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml");

block = soup.find_all("div", class_="bg-scope");
print(block)
```

Comment: вам нужно использовать эмулятор браузера

Comment: А с чем это связано? Защита? Плюс, мне придется проверять содержимое сайта в динамическом режими, разве это возможно с помощью эмулятора?

Comment: @brian дело в том, что запрос через `bs4` вы делаете, как гость, а не как пользователь. Чтобы сделать запрос, как пользователь, вам нужно открыть сессию через `request` и уже из этой сессии делать запрос через `bs4`